# xcodebuild test : Could not launch simulator: -10827

Tags: automated-tests, xcodebuild

I am running my build agent as a launch agent. I get this error when I try to run "xcodebuild test ..."  :

```
2016-07-14 16:31:00.535 xcodebuild[11579:21390] [MT] iPhoneSimulator: Could not launch simulator: -10827 xcodebuild: error: Failed to build project XcodeTestsTest1 with scheme XcodeTestsTest1. Reason: The operation couldnâ€™t be completed. (OSStatus error -10827.)
```

Do you have any idea about how can this issue be solved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had exact same issue.
It happens because Mac OS X doesn't allow an iOS simulator to run in the BACKGROUND.

If you are constructing a Jenkins CI environment, and trying to unit test via the simulator, you can't run the simulator, because Jenkins is basically run as a DAEMON. This also happens if you're running the tests behind environments like tmux or screen.

[Here](http://www.cimgf.com/2015/05/26/setting-up-jenkins-ci-on-a-mac-2/) is a great tutorial to read that can help you fix this.

Cheers!

Comment: You saved me HOURS, I stumbled upon that tutorial but didn't put much attention on that small yet crucial detail!

Comment: That blog was down when I checked. Here's an archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20160506150151/http://www.cimgf.com:80/2015/05/26/setting-up-jenkins-ci-on-a-mac-2/

Answer (score 9):

For me this helped
- close XCode & Simulator (if running)
- open Terminal and type:

```
ps -ax | grep simdeviceio | grep -v grep
```

this had some output on my Mac:

```
50755   ??  Ss     0:00.67 /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SimStreamProcessorServices.simdeviceio/Contents/XPCServices/SimStreamProcessorService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/SimStreamProcessorService
50756   ??  Ss     0:00.07 /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SimAudioProcessorServices.simdeviceio/Contents/XPCServices/SimAudioProcessorService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/SimAudioProcessorService
```

This 2 processes could either manually be killed by typing their PIDs (first number in above lines) with a **kill** command:

```
kill -9 50755 50756
```

or with

```
ps ax | grep simdeviceio | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `apple` icon (top left of screen), then `force quit` then select the simulator

Run the project again

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
xcrun simctl boot "iPhone 7"
```

then

```
run xcodebuild test
```

then after cleanup with

```
xcrun simctl shutdown "iPhone 7"
```

Note: you have to have an active user session running somewhere on the box you are trying to run this on.